# Uploading an Image File to API using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to upload a file using an external API call. However facing some issues when trying to attach the data to the request. I need to attach the file itself and the file name as form data.

I have tried the following:

```
$response = Http::attach('image', $file->path(), $fileName)->withOptions([
                        "multipart" => [
                            "name" => "image",
                            "contents" => fopen($file->path(), "r"),
                            "filename" => $fileName,
                        ],
                        [
                            "name" => "fileName",
                            "contents" => $fileName
                        ]
                        ])->post("<API-ENDPOINT>");
```

But I am getting errors with the post() method expecting an array?

I tried sending it this way too

```
$response = Http::post("<API ENDPOINt>", 
                    [
                        "multipart" => [
                            [
                                "name" => "image",
                                "contents" => file_get_contents("storage/app/images/".$fileName),
                                "filename" => $fileName,
                            ],
                            [
                                "name" => "fileName",
                                "contents" => $fileName,
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]);
```

But this didn't work as expected either, I am getting `file_get_contents(storage/app/images/e5b7e91dfa34a94f09d200f9436ea4e3f3c0d46e-action-helicopter.jpg): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory` even though the file does exist.

Any help here would be appreciated. Doesn't have to use these methods, just any way to POST the File data along with the filename that can be accessed in the form body of the request. Tried checking docs and other forums but no previous answers helped.

Comment: I guess in this case you can use `Storage` facade to retrieve this file from the path.

Comment: i've got the file to open okay, just need to know how to send the file contents along with file name to API endpoint.

Comment: The first code block seems ok, except that `multipart` should be an array, you're missing the opening and closing brackets `[...]` that contain the two items of the `multipart` option. That should solve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it sorted by using the below:

````
$response = Http::attach('image', file_get_contents($file->path()), $fileName)->post("<endpoint>", [
                        "fileName" => $fileName
                    ]);```
````

Comment: It says I can only accept tomorrow, tried initially but it is not working :/. Will do once i can. :)